# Phonegap - Send mail from app

Tags: email, cordova, plugins

I need to add a button on my app, to send a *suggest* mail to my gmail.

I tried some methods but none of them worked.

I was trying, like this:

```
<section data-role="page" id="home">
        <article data-role="content" style="position: fixed;text-align: center;width: 100%;height: 100%;margin:0;padding:0;overflow: hidden;" >
            <!--<a id="go" href="#view-feed-custom"> <img style="max-width: 100%;" src="img/portada.jpg" alt="Logo"> </a>-->

            <script>
            var args = {
                subject: 'Hi there',
                body: 'message to suggest you',
                toRecipients: 'reciver@gmail.com'
            };
            cordova.exec(null, null, "EmailComposer", "showEmailComposer", [args]);
            </script>

            <a href="#" onclick="cordova.exec(null, null, "EmailComposer", "showEmailComposer", [args]);">Enviar Sugerencia 2</a> 

        </article>

    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now trying the both method that u show me...

```
<body onload="init()">

        <!-- START -->
        <section data-role="page" id="home">
            <article data-role="content" style="position: fixed;text-align: center;width: 100%;height: 100%;margin:0;padding:0;overflow: hidden;" >
                <a id="go" href="#view-feed-custom"> <img style="max-width: 100%;" src="img/portada.jpg" alt="Logo"> </a>
            </article>

            <script>
            function send(){
                var args = {
                    subject: 'Hi there',
                    body: 'message to suggest you',
                    toRecipients: 'miemail@gmail.com'
                };
            cordova.exec(null, null, "EmailComposer", "showEmailComposer", [args]);
           }
            </script>
            <button onclick='send();'>Send Mail onClick</button>
            <button href="mailto:email@email.com?cc=email2@email.com&bcc=email3@email.com&subject=The subject of the email&body=The body of the email">Enviar Correo href</button>

        </section>
```

But no run/works...

Thx a lot guys for help me!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.com">email</a>
```

And you can add more parameters like this:

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.com?cc=email2@email.com&bcc=email3@email.com&subject=The subject of the email&body=The body of the email">Send mail with cc, bcc, subject and body</a>
```

This anchor will call the native mailbox of the device.

Comment: are you trying on emulator or real device ?

Comment: real device... and also ADT emulated device

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<a>` tag use `<button>` tag and give  `'onClick=aFunction();'` inside the tag attribute.

and `aFunction()` can be defined as-

```
function aFunction(){
            var args = {
                    subject: 'Hi there',
                    body: 'message to suggest you',
                    toRecipients: 'reciver@gmail.com'
                };
            cordova.exec(null, null, "EmailComposer", "showEmailComposer", [args]);
            }
```

Also, Make sure that u have added the `EmailComposer.js` in the `www` folder and `.m` (assuming that u are on iOS)and `.h` files in `plugins folder`.